# Change subtitle of ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to change subtitle of ListTile once I fetch a data and asign it a new value but I struggle with this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
          backgroundColor: CustomColors.newOrange),
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.newCreme,
      body: ListView.builder(itemCount: 7,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var stringToShow = dateFormat.format(dateTime.add(Duration(days: index))).toString();
            var dateToShow = stringToShow[0].toUpperCase() + stringToShow.substring(1);
            var subtitleText = 'Item';

        return ListTile(
          key: Key(index.toString()),
          title: Text(dateToShow, style: itemsTextStyle(),),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.control_point, color: CustomColors.violetBlue,),
            iconSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(subtitleText, style: subtitleItemsStyle(),),
          onTap: () async {
            var result = await _showTheItems(context, widget.user.id);
            if (result != null) {
              setState(() {
                subtitleText = 'Item... Etiqueta: ${result[0]}';
                print('HERE TEXT HERE ${'Item... Etiqueta: ${result[0]}'}');
              });
            }
          },
        );
          }
      )
    );
  }
```

If I place subtitleText = 'Item'; out of the build method it works but then it changes the subtitle text of all the ListTiles Items. If I put it within the ListView.builder it doesn't reflect the change despite that the 'result' isn't null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats because all your list items are based on the same subtitleText,  if you want independent titles, build a list of strings made of titles, in your case 7 items, use index and attach title to each of the tile based on the index,  and you can update the specific item in the list using the onTap method.

Comment: skjagini is right, setState affects variables under class' scope. Alternative way is to create a stream, make subtitle parameter a StreamBuilder and pass/sink tile's id and new subtitle to stream.

Comment: thanks guys, skjagini, I was thinking of something like this, but it doesn't feel like the right approach.